Weird behavior when logging a Vue2 observer
I'm building an application in Vue2 and I found a behavior that I can't explain.
I have a state variable named important_data. Inside I have an object call parameters, who has a property named parameter_1. When I try to console.log like this : console.log(state.important_data.parameters.parameter_1), I got the correct value (for example value_1).
When I console log the parameters object, I have this output : [parameter_1: (...), __ob__: Observer], where I can find the value by unfolding the element.
But when I do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parameters)) I get the output [].
I think it has something to do with the Observer keyword that I can see next to parameter_1 when I'm logging parameters, but I don't really understand why it behavies like that.
Thanks
EDIT :
here is the object important_data, maybe it will be clearer :
{
   'parameters': {
       'parameter_1': 'value_1'
   }
}


Isn't it an issue with this rather? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log_static#logging_objects Also, please use Vue3, Vue2 is now dead.
